# Scrapy - unexpected return when there is Chinese character in xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am new and I know there is a similar question to this. However, I don't think that problem is solved.

The version of scrapy I am using is 1.0.3 and the environment is in a virtualbox. What I am trying to do is to scrap all information from

> https://bj.lianjia.com/zufang/rs%E8%A5%BF%E4%BA%8C%E6%97%97/

which has "西二旗" in the @title. My script is like this:

```
keywords = u'领秀'

response.xpath('//h2/a[contains(@title,keywrods)]/text()').extract()
```

and the output is like this:

```
[u'\u897f\u4e8c\u65d7\u9886\u79c0\u65b0\u7845\u8c37\u81ea\u4f4f\u578b\u8054\u6392\u522b\u5885', u'\u91d1\u5c71\u8f6f\u4ef6 \u5c0f\u7c73 \u4e94\u5f69\u57ce \u897f\u4e8c\u65d7\u8f6f\u4ef6\u56ed', u'\u9f99\u5174\u56ed\u7cbe\u88c5\u4e24\u5c45\u5ba4\uff0c\u9f99\u6cfd\u56de\u9f99\u89c2\u897f\u4e8c\u65d7\u5317\u6e05\u8def\u3002', u'\u878d\u6cfd\u5609\u56ed\u897f\u4e8c\u65d7\u9f99\u6cfd \u7cbe\u88c5\u4e09\u5c45 \u6708\u5e95\u62ce\u5305\u5165\u4f4f', u'\u9f99\u5174\u56ed\u5317\u533a\u53f2\u8bd7\u7ea7\u7cbe\u88c5\u4fee\u4e24\u5c45\u5ba4\uff0c\u9f99\u6cfd\u56de\u9f99\u89c2\u897f\u4e8c\u65d7\u3002', u'\u4e94\u5f69\u57ce \u5c0f\u7c73 \u91d1\u5c71\u8f6f\u4ef6 \u897f\u4e8c\u65d7\u8f6f\u4ef6\u56ed \u4e0a\u5730\u4e09\u8857', u'\u6b63\u89c4\u5357\u5317\u901a\u900f\u5927\u4e24\u5c45\u6708\u5e95\u5230\u671f\u897f\u4e8c\u65d7\u8f6f\u4ef6\u56ed\u767e\u5ea6', u'\u56de\u9f99\u89c2\u9f99\u6cfd\u897f\u4e8c\u65d7\u5317\u4eac\u4eba\u5bb6\u7cbe\u88c5\u4e24\u5c45\u5bbd\u655e\u660e\u4eae\u62ce\u5305\u4f4f', u'\u897f\u4e8c\u65d7\u9f99\u6cfd\u7535\u68af\u697c\u843d\u5730\u7a97\u5317\u4eac\u4eba\u5bb6\u4e24\u5c45\u7cbe\u88c5\u62ce\u5305\u4f4f']
```

Which returns all the elements not mater containing the keywords or not.

So I really want to know what's happening. I also tried this on my chrome with 
    `$x('//h2/a[contains(@title,"领秀")]')`
and it works fine (only one element returned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't really expand the variable on xpath implicitly like that:

```
keywords = u'领秀'
response.xpath('//h2/a[contains(@title,keywrods)]/text()').extract()
                                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

It should be:

```
keywords = u'领秀'
# python 3.6+
response.xpath(f'//h2/a[contains(@title,"{keywrods}")]/text()').extract()
# python 2/3
response.xpath(u'//h2/a[contains(@title,"{}")]/text()'.format(keywords)).extract()
```

Comment: Thanks. My the version of my python is 2.7 and I tried your method. However, I get an error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in positio 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)". I googled it and the way '.encode()' doesn't work for me as I got another unicode error "ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters"

Comment: I forgot to pre append `u` to the string for python2 example, check my edit.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. It just return all elements as my solution does. Is that a problem with the version of my scrapy. I am using Scrapy 1.0.3 as the docker provided.

Comment: That is indeed a very old version of scrapy (currently the newest one is 1.5.1). Try surrounding keywords wiht quotes; see my edit.